# Need to dictate tomcat deployment order by renaming deployable war files

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, web-applications, sequence

I have the following war files for deployment

```
usapp.war
Phonix.war
VelotownAPI.war
```

I wish to have the deployment-order as below:

```
Phonix.war -- First
usapp.war -- Second
VelotownAPI.war -- Third
```

There are many solutions offered for setting the deployment order. However, The only solution I m looking for is by renaming the deployment files as the filename is considered in the order of deployment.

Thus, I renamed the deployments as below:

```
a_Phonix.war
b_usapp.war
c_VelotownAPI.war
```

However, once the tomcat server starts it does not explode/deploy the above renamed wars in the desired order.

I also tried the below rename but it too did not help get me the desired order.

```
1_Phonix.war
2_usapp.war
3_VelotownAPI.war
```

**Note:**

If I rename the wars like below then the deployment order works!

I also tried the below rename but it too did not help get me the desired order.

```
1.war ---> Phonix.war
2.war ---> usapp.war
3.war ---> VelotownAPI.war
```

Can you please suggest how to rename my war files best so that Tomcat deploys them in the desired order?

Comment: What version of Tomcat?  And why do you think that names determine the deployment order?

Comment: @Pino if i rename as below then  the deployment order works ---> `1.war ---> Phonix.war
2.war ---> usapp.war
3.war ---> VelotownAPI.war` Tomcat version is `9.0.56`

Comment: Works to solve...what?

Answer (score 1):

The [only deployment order](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) that's specified for tomcat is this:

1. Any Context Descriptors will be deployed first.
2. Exploded web applications not referenced by any Context Descriptor will then be deployed. If they have an associated .WAR file in the appBase and it is newer than the exploded web application, the exploded directory will be removed and the webapp will be redeployed from the .WAR
3. .WAR files will be deployed

Relying on anything else is relying on unspecified current behavior. You should instead equip your applications to gracefully handle if another app they depend on is not available. (You should do that anyway, and test for their behavior in that case)

Even if you find the magic names, or if you assume that a context descriptor is read in a certain order: It might not be the order you expect (e.g. it *might* be by date, and sometimes it *might* correlate with the alphabetical order - until the next update)

Accept that deployment order is unspecified (also by the underlying specification) and prepare for it.

Alternatively (though still not recommended) you can script your deployment. E.g. start up an empty tomcat, and remote-control it through the manager-app and its API - there, of course, you can implement any order you like.

Comment: i m considering that the option 1 & 2 in your answers is not present (irrelevant) considering we are setting up the infra / instance on the fly. For option `3. .WAR files will be deployed` is where I m trying to play around with name preferences as considered by tomcat.

Comment: I understand. And no matter what you find out, it might break at any moment in the future. You'll have to accept that the order is unspecified apart from the list that I've given above, and plan for it. Unless you let the WAR files appear one after the other - e.g. through a mechanism like the last paragraph, or just by filecopy.